# Use python wand to grayscale image

Tags: python, imagemagick, grayscale, magickwand, wand

I want to use the Python API binding for ImageMagick http://wand-py.org to directly manipulate images. I am however not able to deduce from the documentation how to use a grayscale transformation. Can anybody provide information on this problem?

```
from wand.image import Image
try:
  with Image(file=path) as img:
    img.grayscale() # PSEUDOCODE for my given problem
except:
  pass
```

Answer (score 20):

This can be achieved by setting the colorspace of the image.

```
from wand.image import Image
with Image(filename='color.jpg') as img:
    img.type = 'grayscale';
    img.save(filename='grayscale.jpg');
```

further reading:

- http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/wand/image.html#wand.image.IMAGE_TYPES
- http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/colorspace.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct code:

you need to transform the colorspace:

```
  with Image(filename=str(f)) as img:
        img.transform_colorspace('gray')
```